# SQL Query Issue (Date compare)

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I'm trying to create a query which will only show me the "articles" which is below the publish date. For example I may have an article which has a publish date of tomorrow afternoon, this is the query I made but doesn't seem to work correctly:

```
SELECT a.id, CASE WHEN a.created_by_alias > ' ' THEN a.created_by_alias ELSE ua.name     END AS author 
FROM #__content AS a 
LEFT JOIN #__users AS ua ON ua.id = a.created_by 
LEFT JOIN #__categories AS c ON c.id = a.catid 
WHERE a.state='1' 
AND c.id!=1618 
AND a.publish_up >= NOW() 
AND a.title LIKE '%Europa no es una broma%'
```

The publish_up date is returned as this: 2013-12-19 20:55:00 and todays date which would be now() is returned the same way: 2013-12-18 09:31:30 (Both same format).

What I want is only those articles which are below todays date.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What's the column type for `publish_up`? I'm also not clear on what you mean by "below the publish date"... do you want to get the published or not yet published articles out of your query?

Comment: This is not a good question, because it doesn't describe the exact problem. Table structure, example data, expected results based on that data, current results, error messages, if any...

Comment: Sorry for not completing the information, I have edited the question, hope this works out better.

Comment: `a.publish_up >= NOW()` doesn't really match well with "only those articles which are _below_ todays date". `<=` sounds more right than `>=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT a.id, CASE WHEN a.created_by_alias > ' ' THEN a.created_by_alias ELSE ua.name     END AS author 
FROM #__content AS a 
LEFT JOIN #__users AS ua ON ua.id = a.created_by 
LEFT JOIN #__categories AS c ON c.id = a.catid 
WHERE a.state='1' 
AND c.id!=1618 
AND DATE(a.publish_up) < Date(NOW()) 
AND a.title LIKE '%Europa no es una broma%'
```

Make use of DATE() function that returns the value to a date `yyyy-mm-dd`